# ListView Style Trigger to change string format

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

I am trying to add an asterisk to a listview.item, using a style trigger. However, the below code seems to ignore the ContentStringFormat. The background of the item is set to red correctly. Can somebody spot why setter property for the ContentStringFormat doesn't work?

```
<ListView.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
          <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsTrue}" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                   <Setter Property="ContentStringFormat" Value="{}{0} *}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```

Comment: Is the trailing curly brace intentional? The one after the `*` because they don't match.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested your code and can confirm that the curly brace at the end of your `ContentFormatString` is causing the issue. Remove it and use it like this:

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsTrue}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="ContentStringFormat" Value="{}{0} *"/><!-- Here is the change-->
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```

Comment: Hmm i was hoping that this would fix it but it is still not working

Comment: You would have to share more xaml wit us. I tested the code that you provided and the `ListView` produces items with `*` at the end with red backgrdounds (with the fix provided). I used mine inside a grid in the `MainWindow.xaml`.

Comment: I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jaworekplay/96056ef34306b016aca8b7bcd3030a47) for you to have a look.